# Error when calling cvlc through Popen in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, vlc, popen

I'm trying to pipe h264 to vlc in python.  I'm having trouble opening the cvlc program while calling it in Popen.  This is the code.

```
    self.vlc = subprocess.Popen([
    "cvlc", "-vvv", "stream:///dev/stdin", "--sout \'#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}\' :demux=h264"
    ], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This is the vlc error

```
vlc: unknown option or missing mandatory argument `--sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264'
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours with different types of string formatting.

Comment: There is an --sout parameter as seen [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/#RTSP_live_streaming) and turns out subprocess doesn't handle spaces in parameters well.  [This turned out to be my solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655173/is-python-subprocess-popen-accept-space-in-path/25655627#25655627)

Comment: shlex.split works even better, I posted working code [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59512/raspberry-streaming-using-vlc-picamera-python/68806#68806).  Thanks for you help, don't think I would have gotten it working otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**:  I'm having trouble opening the cvlc program while calling it in Popen.

Use `shlex.quote(..`. to get a shell-escaped version of your Parameters.

> Python 3.6 Documentation:[shlex.quote](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote)
>
> **`shlex.quote(s)`**
> Return a shell-escaped version of the string s. The returned value is a string that can safely be used as one token in a shell command line, for cases where you cannot use a list